# Copy mysql row value from row below?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

My problem:

```
+------+--------------+
|  SKU |    Image     |
+------+--------------+
|  123 |    bild 1    |
| NULL |    bild 11   |
|  124 |    bild 2    |
| NULL |    bild 22   |
|  125 |    bild 3    |
| NULL |    bild 33   |
+------+--------------+
```

And I need this:

```
+-------+------+--------------+
|   id  |  SKU |    Image     |
+-------+------+--------------+
|  123  |  123 |    bild 1    |
|  123  | NULL |    bild 11   |
|  124  |  124 |    bild 2    |
|  124  | NULL |    bild 22   |
|  125  |  125 |    bild 3    |
|  125  | NULL |    bild 33   |
+-------+------+--------------+
```

I whant to copy the sku value from row below if the rows sku is NULL.

I tried:

```
SELECT 
    * , 
    @lastid := sku, 
    IF( sku =  '', @lastid , sku ) AS id 
FROM table;
```

Any idea?

Comment: And what column determines the order of your table?

Comment: SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is no concept of "row above" or "row below" unless a column explicitly specifies the ordering.

Comment: to fix your logic for the query its backwards.. it should be `SELECT * , IF( sku = NULL, @lastid , sku ) AS id, @lastid := sku FROM table`

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/6051/what-is-the-default-order-of-records-for-a-select-statement-in-mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NOTE:
this assumes that your image can be used to order the data.... from what I can tell it looks like its incremented which would be a usable order with the data provided

```
select *, IF( sku IS NULL, @lastid , sku ) AS id, @lastid := sku
from temp
cross join(select @lastid := null)t
order by image;
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/14b1f/8)

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it using procedures.

You can create a procedure that check the below row and make what you need. Is you have sequential ID you can just make a -1 in your actual row id, or create a function to get this below row (that makes more sense).

Comment: this can be done simply with user defined variables.. but the issue is there is no specific order that can be given. using procedures is way too complicated

Comment: You need a field to be based to properly order it. If you don't it's impossible to make it since you don't have a logic way to do it.

The best solution is this case could be create a auto-increment filed called order or something like. So you have a field to create this order. But if you have other variables that make impossible to use this column you just can't do it.

Comment: i know.. but the thing is using procedures is wayy to complicated